# how to match searching ean code with results

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've written code that looks for a code using a list and adds the result to the list if it matches.
the principle of operation is as follows:

1. fetches code from excel file.
2. executes the request and checks if there is a product for the given ean that has the data-offer-ean attribute equal to the symbol in the request.
3. if there is a div it adds it to the list of matches, if not it adds it to the list of unmatches.

The problem is that the results contain a lot of incorrect codes that are not actually on the page, but appear on the list. Do you have any suggestions?
This is my code:

```
df = pd.read_excel('eanBR.xlsx', dtype="int64")
mylist = df['ean'].tolist()
dopasowane = []
niedopasowane = []

def get_ean(symbol):

    response = requests.get(f"https://www.bricomarche.pl/search?query%5Bquerystring%5D={symbol}")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    div = soup.find('div', attrs={'data-offer-ean': True})
    if div:
        ean = div['data-offer-ean']
        if str(ean) == str(symbol):
            dopasowane.append(ean)
        else:
            niedopasowane.append(ean)
    else:
        niedopasowane.append(symbol)
    return ean

bar = IncrementalBar('Pobieranie danych', max=len(mylist), suffix='%(percent).1f%% - %(eta)ds')

for item in mylist:
    try:
        ean_result = get_ean(item)
        bar.next()
    except Exception as e:
        bar.next()

bar.finish()

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws_dopasowane = wb.active
ws_dopasowane.title = 'Dopasowane'
ws_niedopasowane = wb.create_sheet('Niedopasowane')


for idx, ean in enumerate(dopasowane, start=1):
    ws_dopasowane.cell(row=idx, column=1, value=ean)

for idx, ean in enumerate(niedopasowane, start=1):
    ws_niedopasowane.cell(row=idx, column=1, value=ean)

wb.save('wynik.xlsx')
```

Comment: We would need to see some test data of the input excel file with wrong data and an expected output from that.

Comment: fo example ean 5904517008557  5904517008564 one ot them should be matched and another one should be unmatched.

Comment: Can you reduce the example code to a minimum ([mcve]) and focus on your question or add clarifying details, please?
The background is that both ean mentioned `[5904517008557,5904517008564]` would end up in `dopasowane`, which is correct from my point of view.  thanks

Comment: the main problem is that if he enters the ean code, there are usually one, two or three results per page.
My point is that it finds a specific div of this product whose value of the "data-offer-ean" attribute is the same as the ean code from the query, and only then saves it as matched.

Answer (score 0):

In case that there is more than one element you have to use `find_all()` or `select()` and iterate the `resultSet` to check for your value or you select your element more specific, if you just focus that exact one:

```
soup.select_one(f'[data-offer-ean="{symbol}"]')
```

##### Example

```
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

mylist = [5904517008557,5904517008564,8888888888]
dopasowane = []
niedopasowane = []

def get_ean(symbol):

    response = requests.get(f"https://www.bricomarche.pl/search?query%5Bquerystring%5D={symbol}")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    
    if div:=soup.select_one(f'[data-offer-ean="{symbol}"]'):
        dopasowane.append(symbol)
        return symbol
    else:
        niedopasowane.append(symbol)
        return None
    

for item in mylist:
    print(get_ean(item))

print(dopasowane,niedopasowane)
```

##### Results

```
5904517008557
5904517008564
None
[5904517008557, 5904517008564] [8888888888]
```